# Laravel 8 problemas con queues (mailables)

Tags: laravel-8, queue

Estoy enviando correos con Laravel de la siguiente manera

```
foreach ($toEmail as $key => $data) {
  Mail::to($data->staff_email)
  ->send(
     new NewAppEmail($data)
  );
}
```

en `app/mail/NewAppEmail` tengo lo siguiente:

```
 class NewAppEmail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue{
     use Queueable, SerializesModels;

     public $data;

     public function __construct($data)
    {
       $this->data = $data;
    }

   public function build()
     {
        $this->subject(str_replace('_', " ", config('app.name', 'Laravel')))
        ->view('staff.mail.staff.apps.NewAppEmail')
        ->with(
            [
               'service' => $this->data->treatment->service->service,
               'procedure' => $this->data->treatment->procedure->procedure,
               'package' => $this->data->treatment->package->package,
               'patient_name' => $this->data->treatment->name,
               'patient_phone' => $this->data->treatment->phone,
               'patient_email' => $this->data->treatment->email,
               'staff_email' => $this->data->staff_email,
               'staff_name' => $this->data->staff_name,
               'url' => $this->data->app_id,
           ]
      );
    }
}
```

en los logs me sale lo siguiente:

```
[2022-04-03 12:42:24] local.ERROR: Undefined variable $service (View: /var/www/dominio.test/resources/views/staff/mail/staff/apps/NewAppEmail.blade.php)
```

Si a la clase `NewAppEmail` le quito el `Implements SholdQueue`, si envía los correos, pero no se ponen en cola.

La pregunta, ¿por qué al ponerlos en cola dice que la variable no existe y al enviarlos sin cola se van perfectamente?

¿Alguna ayuda? ¿Qué hago mal, será la caché?

Comment: Qué es `Mail` ? Es una clase auxiliar que te hiciste? Porque tu clase es Mailable así que tiene su propio `to` y `send`

Comment: Ya quedo solo debía reiniciar supervisor